# what is the Difference between Angular 1.X vs 2.X

Tags: angularjs

I am familiar with Angular 1.X but i Noticed about 2.X which is differ than 1.X is it worth to spend time to learn 2.X instead 1.X?

so which is preferable for beginner? does angular 1.X is LTS ?

what is the Main difference Between both?

Comment: This is not a coding/programming question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/tour to check how to make questions here, also wich tematics.
For this question there are plenty of blogs and forums, [just like this one](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/differences-between-angular-1-and-2)

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2.0 is totally different from 1.0; it is completely rewritten.it comes with TypeScript (ECMA 6 &at Script).means components are the basic building blocks for UI. In Angular 2.0 there are no controllers create only directives. Roughly speaking, a component in Angular 2 replaces what was known as a directive and becomes the foundation of any Angular 2 application. Improved Dependency Injection with TypeScript Generics. Angular 2 says Goodbye to $scope with Ultra-Fast Chance Detection.